# c program to check the user entered pin with the already set 4 digit pin

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

Enter a 4 digit Pin and check whether it is correct or not.

The program masks the 4 digit pin with * but the problem i am having is i want to ignore all the other characters except numbers and also i just want the user to enter exactly 4 digits.

I hope you guys understand my code

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAB 9
#define BKSP 8
#define SPACE 32

void main(){

    int pin = 1234 ;
    char apin[4] , ch;
    int attempt ;
    int i;
    int pw = 0; 

    for(attempt=1; attempt<=3; attempt++) {

    printf("Enter 4 digit pin code:\n");

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        ch = getch();
       
        if(ch == BKSP)
        {
            if(i>0){
                i--;
                printf("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else if(ch==TAB || ch == SPACE ){
            continue;
        }
        else{
        apin[i] = ch;
        ch = '*' ;
        printf("%c",ch);
        }
    }
    apin[i] = ' ';
    printf("\n");
    pw = atoi(apin) ;
    //printf("%d\n",pw);//

    if(pw != 1234){
        printf("Invalid Pin\n");
        printf("You have %d attempts remaining\n",3-attempt);

    }
    else{
        printf("Your have entered the correct pin code\n");
        break;
    }
    }
}```
````

Comment: "_i want to ignore all the other characters except numbers_" - Why? That gives a potential intruder information you probably not want the intruder to have.

Comment: After the loop, `apin[i] = ' ';` exceeds the array bounds, *and* the `char apin[4]` cannot be the NUL-terminated string required by `atoi()` anyway.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "Your have entered" should be "You have entered"

Comment: `pw = atoi(apin) ;` will validate input like `"+1234"`.

Comment: You will need to check whether the input character is a digit (similar to what you do for `BKSP`, if the input character is not a digit, ignore it or print a message), `switch` statements can come handy if you find that multiple `if-else` statements make the code hard to read.

In the case of `BKSP` you have to check and modify if needed `apin` as well.
In case of `TAB` or `SPACE`, you have to take care of the counter `i` as well, other wise your pin will comprise less than 4 digits.

Also, please clarify what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get Only Numbers as input -

```
int count = 0;
while(count<4){
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    if(ch>='0' && ch<='9'){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike getch scanf will wait for the whole line to be entered and echo the characters. Also, you are not saving the entered characters.

Comment: @stark  buddy thanks for correcting me in case of scanf, and about storing characters I was just giving him clue for checking condition,though storing characters can be done with help of arrays :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Enter a 4 digit Pin and check whether it is correct or not.

Read a line of user input with `fgets()`

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; // Lop off potential trailing \n
```

Test input and accumulate `pin`.

```
  // to ignore all the other characters except numbers and 
  // also i just want the user to enter exactly 4 digits.
  unsigned pin = 0;
  size_t count = 0;
  for (char *s = buf; *s; s++) {
    if (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
      pin = pin * 10 + *s - '0';
      count++;
    }
  }
  success = count == 4;
```

IMO, better to not ignore others, only digits allowed

```
  unsigned pin = 0;
  size_t count = 0;
  for (char *s = buf; *s >= '0' && *s <= '9'; s++) {
    pin = pin * 10 + *s - '0';
    count++;
  }
  success = *s == '\0' && count == 4;
}
```